# Use Spring Boot to package and run an existing WAR file

Tags: spring-boot

Is there a way I can use Spring Boot to package and run an existing WAR file without modifying  the WAR?

Thanks!

--john

Comment: In case all you're trying to do is run up a WAR in an embedded container, both Maven and Gradle have plugins to support this. For example: http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Boot plugins to create a WAR that contained the embedded container jars, and a launcher for a main method. You'd have to provide a main() method, so really that's where it would potentially become problematic. Look for tutorials on the web about how to launch an embedded container, or inspect the code in Boot that does it. Spring Boot has such a lot of convenient embedded container features and you might end up re-writing quite a bit of it.